# Adding background attachment as fixed it is reducing the height of the image

Tags: css

Hi i have written  css for fixed header that is banner image should be fixed when we scroll the page the content should be scrolled on the top of the image but if i give the background attachment as fixed the height of the image is getting small and getting blank space at the top  as shown in below diagram.

[image]

Css i have written this

```
.partnerspage {
background-image: url(http://www.server.com/bl/banner-1920x375-Partners.jpg);   
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-attachment: fixed; 
}
```

Here is the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/xykchmg9/1/

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you will add you HTML markup or create a code snippet.

Comment: have you tried to add backgroun-size ?

Comment: @godfather i have given background-size:100% as well and background-size:100% 375px as well but it didnt work

Comment: i meant like background-size:contain or cover

Comment: @godfather if i give background size as cover image is getting zoomed

Comment: i cant see your full code but does the wrapper have a height ? or if you can create an example so we can help you

Comment: @godfather  https://jsfiddle.net/xykchmg9/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
background: transparent url(http://www.server.com/blue/br-banner11.jpg) 0% 0%/100% 70% no-repeat fixed;
```

i have fixed the background attachment by adding like this.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are looking for here it is: this css can fix your problem I hope

```
body {margin:0;}

    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .navbar a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }

    .navbar a:hover {
      background: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }

    .main {
      padding: 16px;
      margin-top: 30px;
      height: 1500px; /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
    }
    .parallax {
      background-image: url("https://dmm8trq3la0u4.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/how-to-setup-website.jpg");
      min-height: 500px; 
      /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    .contain{
      height:1000px;
      background-color:#ccc;
      font-size:36px;
      padding:24px;
    }
```

Html goes here...

```
<div class="navbar">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
      <div class="parallax"></div>

      <div class="contain">
      Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.
      This div is just here to enable scrolling.
      Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.
      </div>
    </div>
```

[Codepen example you can check it from here](https://codepen.io/rajeshkumarsah/pen/ZZopPa)

Comment: If i am giving background size as cover image is getting zoomed

Comment: It will take 100% width if you give backgroud-size:cover, you can fix it like this way background-size: 300px 100px; as per your design requirement hope this can fix your problem @tester